# Zookeeper setting up clusters

Tags: configuration, apache-zookeeper

Hello i am trying to set up Zookeeper in clustered environment. For this i have made the zoo.cfg as:

```
tickTime=2000                # REQUIRED - This will be the basis of timing 

events (milliseconds)
initLimit=5                  # REQUIRED - Amount of ticks in initialization
syncLimit=2                  # REQUIRED - Amount of ticks to determine if node is still connected
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper   # REQUIRED - Where to store zookeeper sync data
clientPort=2181              # REQUIRED - Port which clients connect to
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 # or "0.0.0.0:2888:3888" if server.1 is the current node
server.2=server2host:2888:3888 # or "0.0.0.0:2888:3888" if server.2 is the current node
server.3=server3host:2888:3888 # or "0.0.0.0:2888:3888" if server.N is the current node
```

When trying to start foreground the current node i.e. 1 i am getting the error:

```
if server.1 is the current node does not have the form host:port 
or host:port:portor host:port:port:type
```

But i believe the current node seems to be ok.
Can anyone guide on what could be the missing thing here.

-V

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out, somehow the comments were not getting treated as comments and hence the startup is throwing error, modifying

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=server2host:2888:3888
server.3=server3host:2888:3888
```

works!
-Vaibhav

Comment: having the comments on the same line  treats it as a single value line
`initLimit=5                  # REQUIRED - Amount of ticks in initialization`
here initLimit has a value **5                  # REQUIRED - Amount of ticks in initialization**